# React Native - Is it possible to control the speed at which the ScrollView scrolls

Tags: reactjs, scrollview, react-native, react-native-ios

I have looked at many posts and they seem to suggest that it is not possible. However, they are very old posts. I am curious if this is possible now.

I am using expo in my project and referred the below,

https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz

I don't seem to find the duration variable as suggested in the below pull request that is requested as a feature.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17422

Any help would be appreciated.Any workarounds if this is not possible? I am thinking of setting a time interval and wrap the scrollview around but I am not sure if that works.

Comment: check ```decelerationRate``` of ScrollView.

Comment: @SDushan I think the deceleration rate is the speed at which the scrollView scrolls after the user removes his/her finger. In my case, upon the press of a button, I would need the scrollView to scroll with a custom speed, more like an auto-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

would like to know why you need to do this. Maybe understand we'll can help with other way.

Comment: Upon click of a button, the content in the scroll view scrolls while there is an audio playback running behind. The scroll speed has to be consistent with the pace the content is readout.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by having setInterval call a function(in which you define the logic or the pace at which the scroll should move).

```
this.interval= setInterval(this.scrollwithSpeed, 100); // Set the function to this timer

scrollwithSpeed() {
  position = this.state.currentPosition + x; // x decides the speed and currentPosition is set to 0 initially.
  this.scrollObject.scrollTo(
      { y: position, animated: true }
  );
  this.setState({ currentPosition: position });
}
```

Make sure you call clearInterval(this.interval) after it is done.